# Change wording on post checkout account offer

Tags: magento2.2, create-account

I need to change the wording on the post checkout page where it offers the user a chance to create an acount and it says "You can track your order status by creating an account." because they wont be able to track the order there, only view it as history. We still want to give them a chance to create an account so I dont want to just turn off the box.
Developer hints point me at:
 magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/registration.phtml
But this file is just a js call and I dont know where that line is generated.

[image: Need to change this line]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following file is the actual template:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/registration.html

You can modify this template in theme level or overwriting following js

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/registration.js

Any text change you can use translation instead of modify file. 
[Check here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/theme_dictionary.html) and [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html)

***Note: don't modify core file***

Comment: I have gone through these solutions and none have had any effect for me so far. I have made sure to run cache:flush, and even static-content:deploy. even setup upgrade when doing the language pack and have not achieved any change to that line.

Comment: Did you check in theme level? If your existing theme already overwrite this template then you need to modify there. Location should be app/design/frontend/[YourThemeVendor]/[YourTheme]/Magento_Checkout/template/registration.html. You definitely made some mistake.

Comment: Figured out the browser cache was not clearing with ctrl-F5 because the page changes. After clearing it manually the change from the translation file at  [ThemeVendor]/[Theme]/i18n/en_US.csv showed up.
The changes to registration.html still dont show up, but Im calling it solved with the translation file. 
Thanks for the help